# Ansible The task includes an option with an undefined variable

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible to deploy a website. But I get this error:

```
fatal: [lxc-server]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: [{u'authorized_keys': u'{{ delivery_authorized_keys }}', u'group': u'{{ magento_webserver_group }}', u'name': u'{{ magento_project_user }}'}]: {{ http_group_name }}: 'http_group_name' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/jredor/projets/webstore/architecture/provisioning/provision.yml': line 32, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: \"Prepare the delivery_users object\"\n      ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: [{u'authorized_keys': u'{{ delivery_authorized_keys }}', u'group': u'{{ magento_webserver_group }}', u'name': u'{{ magento_project_user }}'}]: {{ http_group_name }}: 'http_group_name' is undefined"}
```

I understand that there is something undefined, but the thing is, it was developed by someone else and it should work perfectly, and this someone else isn't there anymore. Here is the provision.yml:

```
---
# load variables for each servers
- hosts:
    - dbservers
    - cacheservers
    - searchservers
    - webservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  tasks:
    - include: includes/include-vars.yml

# Prepare the delivery authorized keys
- hosts:
    - dbservers
    - cacheservers
    - searchservers
    - webservers
  connection: local

  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
    tmp_delivery_users:
      - name:   "{{ magento_project_user }}"
        group:  "{{ magento_webserver_group }}"
        authorized_keys: "{{ delivery_authorized_keys }}"

  tasks:
    - name: "Prepare the list of the authorized keys for delivery - Extra Keys"
      set_fact: delivery_authorized_keys="{{ delivery_authorized_extra_keys }}"

    - name: "Prepare the delivery_users object"
      set_fact: delivery_users="{{ tmp_delivery_users }}"

# add hosts alias on Servers
- hosts:
    - dbservers
    - cacheservers
    - searchservers
    - webservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  tasks:
    - include: includes/init-hosts.yml
      with_items: "{{ specific_hosts|default([]) }}"

# add magento hosts alias on WebServers
- hosts:
    - webservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  tasks:
    - include: includes/init-hosts.yml
      with_items: "{{ magento_server_alias|default([]) }}"

# Generic behaviors on all servers
- hosts:
    - dbservers
    - cacheservers
    - searchservers
    - webservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  roles:
    - role: ansible-basicserver

# Generic usage of the ansible roles - DB Server
- hosts: dbservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  roles:
    - role: ansible-mysql-server

# Generic usage of the ansible roles - Cache Server
- hosts: cacheservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  roles:
    - {
        role: ansible-redis,
        redis_instance_name: "magento_cache",
        redis_setting_port:  "{{ magento_cache_port }}",
        redis_setting_save:  "{{ redis_setting_save_cache }}"
      }
    - {
        role: ansible-redis,
        redis_instance_name: "magento_session",
        redis_setting_port:  "{{ magento_cache_session_port }}",
        redis_setting_save:  "{{ redis_setting_save_session }}"
      }

# Generic usage of the ansible roles - Search Server
- hosts: searchservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  roles:
    - role: ansible-elasticsearch

# Prepare php parameters
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  tasks:
    - include: includes/prepare-php-parameters.yml

# Generic usage of the ansible roles - Webserver Server
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  roles:
    - role: ansible-php
    - role: ansible-apache
    - role: ansible-varnish
    - role: ansible-nginx

# Specific usage of the ansible roles - Webserver Server - Dev Tools
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    ansible_user: "root"
  roles:
    - { role: ansible-npm, when: magento_install_maildev or magento_install_grunt }
    - { role: ansible-maildev, when: magento_install_maildev }

  tasks:
  - name: "Install NPM package: grunt-cli"
    npm: name="grunt-cli" global=yes
    when: magento_install_grunt

  - name: "Add delivery user in groups"
    user:
      name: "{{ magento_project_user }}"
      groups: "{{ magento_delivery_groups }}"

  - name: "Create {{ magento_source_path }} folder"
    file:
      path:  "{{ magento_source_path }}"
      state: directory
      owner: "{{ magento_project_user }}"
      group: "{{ magento_project_group }}"
      mode:  "u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX"

# Specific task for Magento 2
  - name: "Check if Magento app/etc/env.php exists"
    stat:
      path: "{{ magento_source_path }}/app/etc/env.php"
    register: magento_app_etc_env

  - name: "Update app/etc/env.php configuration file"
    template:
      src: "templates/magento/env.php.j2"
      dest: "{{ magento_source_path }}/app/etc/env.php"
      owner: "{{ magento_project_user }}"
      group: "{{ magento_webserver_group }}"
      mode: "u=rw,g=rw,o=r"
    vars:
        magento_cache_database: "{{ magento_cache_database_for_run }}"
    when: magento_app_etc_env.stat.exists

# Update permissions
  - include: includes/permissions-tasks-full.yml
```

The error is triggered there:

```
  - name: "Prepare the delivery_users object"
  set_fact: delivery_users="{{ tmp_delivery_users }}"
```

So, like I said I understand that http_group_name is undefined, but how can I define it? How can I debug this?

I noticed that http_group_name is defined in the distro-vars, where for every distri there is a yml file. There is CentOS-7, Debian-8, Debian-9, RadHat-7 and Ubuntu-16.04. But my distri is Ubuntu 20.04. Could it be the problem? Should I create a Ubuntu-20.04.yml?
Thanks

Edit:
my env.php.j2

```
    {% set document_root_is_pub = 'false' %}
{% if magento_mode == 'production' %}{% set document_root_is_pub = 'true' %}{% endif %}
<?php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'host' => '{{ magento_db_host }}',
                'dbname' => '{{ magento_db_name }}',
                'username' => '{{ magento_db_user }}',
                'password' => '{{ magento_db_password }}',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true),
            ),
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '{{ magento_db_table_prefix }}',
    ),
    'backend' => array(
        'frontName' => '{{ magento_backend_frontname }}',
    ),
    'install' => array(
        'date' => '{{ magento_install_date }}',
    ),
    'crypt' => array(
        'key' => '{{ magento_crypt_key }}',
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => array(
            'host' => '{{ magento_cache_session_host }}',
            'port' => '{{ magento_cache_session_port }}',
            'database' => '{{ magento_cache_session_database }}',
            'disable_locking' => '1',
        ),
    ),
    'cache' => array(
        'frontend' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'id_prefix' => '{{ magento_cache_id_prefix }}',
                'backend_options' => array(
                    'server' => '{{ magento_cache_host }}',
                    'port' => '{{ magento_cache_port }}',
                    'persistent' => '',
                    'database' => '{{ magento_cache_database }}',
                    'force_standalone' => '0',
                    'connect_retries' => '1',
                    'read_timeout' => '10',
                    'automatic_cleaning_factor' => '0',
                    'compress_data' => '1',
                    'compress_tags' => '1',
                    'compress_threshold' => '20480',
                    'compression_lib' => 'gzip',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'http_cache_hosts' => array(
{% set loop_index = 0 %}
{% for host in magento_http_cache_hosts %}
        {{ loop_index }} => array(
            'host' => '{{ host.host }}',
            'port' => '{{ host.port }}',
        ),
{% set loop_index = loop_index + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
    ),
    'MAGE_MODE' => '{{ magento_mode }}',
    'directories' => array(
        'document_root_is_pub' => {{ document_root_is_pub }},
    ),
    'queue' => array(
        'amqp' => array(
            'host' => '',
            'port' => '',
            'user' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'virtualhost' => '/',
            'ssl' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'resource' => array(
        'default_setup' => array(
            'connection' => 'default',
        ),
    ),
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'cache_types' => array(
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'target_rule' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
    ),
);
```

I don't have any "http_group_name" in here. Is this the error? Should I define it there? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: If really the error is triggered by the step you are showing, then there is definitly something you fail to show us here. What I suspect, though, is that you have a variable `http_group_name` used in *templates/magento/env.php.j2* that you indeed forgot to set in your playbook.

Comment: The error points at: `/home/jredor/projets/webstore/architecture/provisioning/provision.yml` at `line 32, column 7`. You may get your answer if you look into that, or update the question.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I edited the question about the http_group_name

Comment: @SeshadriC Like I said, the error line 32 is the line:
- name: "Prepare the delivery_users object"
That's why I don't understand. But the error also talks about the http_group_name, so I looked into this and edited the question

Comment: Looks like OS/distro dependent variables are being loaded. I think you should have a vars file for your distro. It's documented in [tips and tricks](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/os-dependent-tasks/variables/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I was on debian 10 on my container I did a new container on debian 9 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the distro. Since I was on debian 10 on my container I did a new container on debian 9 and it worked.